# TryParse without Actual Parsing or any other Alternative for Checking Text Format with Performance Benefit

Tags: c#, parsing

I currently am making my own library, called `TextCheckerExtension` which basically tries to check Text Format before further processing (short code snippet shown below).

Now, I know what I am doing is quite similar to `Parse` or `TryParse` The only difference between this and all the `Parse` is that this does not generate any parsed object. It simply checks the string.

My questions are:

1. Both `Parse` and `TryParse` generate parsed object. Do the overhead of generating Parsed object in case we only want to check the validity of the `string` input really affects the performance of the methods (Any example for this case)? That is, self-created checking method without generating parsed object will be way faster.
2. Is there any alternative way (built-in) in C# to check various string format validity without generated parsed object?
3. Could `Regex` be an alternative option?

Any input for this matter will be very much appreciated.

---

```
public static bool IsPureHex(string str) {
  return IsPureHex(str, int.MaxValue); //assuming very high value!
}

public static bool IsPureHex(string str, int maxNibble) {
  if (str.Length > maxNibble) //if the length is violated, it is considered failed
    return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(maxNibble, str.Length); i++)
    if (!((char.IsDigit(str, i)) || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'F')) || ((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'f'))))
      return false;
  return true;
}

public static bool IsHex(string str) {
  if (str.Length <= 2 || (str[0] != '0') || !((str[1] == 'x') || (str[1] == 'X'))) //Check input validity
    return false;
  for (int i = 2; i < str.Length; i++)
    if (!((char.IsDigit(str, i)) || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'F')) || ((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'f'))))
      return false;
  return true;
}

public static bool IsFloat(string str) { //another criterion for float, giving "f" in the last part?
  int dotCounter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) { //Check if it is float
    if (!(char.IsDigit(str, i)) && (str[i] != '.'))
      return false;
    else if (str[i] == '.')
      ++dotCounter; //Increase the dotCounter whenever dot is found
    if (dotCounter > 1) //If there is more than one dot for whatever reason, return error
      return false;
  }
  return dotCounter == 1 && str.Length > 1;
}

public static bool IsDigitsOnly(string str) {
  foreach (char c in str)
    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
      return false;      
  return str.Length >= 1; //there must be at least one character here to continue
}

public static bool IsInt(string str) { //is not designed to handle null input or empty string
  return str[0] == '-' && str.Length > 1 ? IsDigitsOnly(str.Substring(1)) : IsDigitsOnly(str);
}
```

Comment: I think the additional overhead is probably not worth the worry of having a potentially broken implementation of `TryParse/Parse` etc...

Comment: Yah, any input now will help me to consider if I were to stop my project or not actually... I would like to know if there is anyone experiencing similar issue with better solution or if the established solution is already considered good enough...

Comment: It depends on the use case IMO. If you're going to be parsing a lot of strings, for example, you could be generating significant GC pressure. If the inputs are string, I think regex validation is an option. If you pre-compile your expressions, you might end up being on-par with `Parse`/`TryParse`.

Comment: My experience is that, by the time you've done the work needed to correctly evaluate a string, you generally also already have all of the information you need to create the object right there ready to go.

Comment: Check out the ***Irony*** library here: http://irony.codeplex.com/

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks, will take a look on that! I have been continuing this project for quite a while though. See if the library could provide better solution.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn in general cases, I cannot but agree with your comment. But just recently I was exposed to computational linguistic area where it is more common to identify a text format without necessarily wanted to use it for computation. I am not aware if there is any tools currently which are already provided for that. My aim at this point is just to test the performance under the given case. I also am willing to know if you are aware of any better tool/method for the given scenario.

Answer (score 3):

It ***does*** make a difference.

To my surprise: as I continue this project out of curiosity, I found out that doing the actual parsing and simply checking if a string is of certain format ***does*** make a significant difference in time performance.

In my experiment below, by creating checker without parser, we could gain 33.77% to 58.26% time gain as compared to using built-in `TryParse`. In addition, I also compare my extension with `VB.Net` `IsNumeric` in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information` dll.

Here are the (1) tested code, (2) testing scenario, (3) testing code, and (4) testing result (notes are added in each part whenever necessary):

---

#### Tested Code:

Here is the tested code, my extension code named `Extension.Checker.Text`. I only tested scenarios for generic `integer` and `float/double` (with/without dot - perhaps better termed fraction-ed number) so far. By **generic** `integer` I mean that the maximum and minimum value *range* (such as -128 to 127 for 8-bit signed integer) is unchecked. This code is just to determine if a text is `integer` *as human understands it* without looking at its range. That goes the same for `float/double`.

Compare with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number) post which has 400+ upvotes on its answer by the time this answer is posted, I believe it is safe to assume that generally we will use `int.TryParse` to test if a text is an `integer` or not as a first try (albeit its range is limited to `-2e9` to `2e9`) for generic `integer` text. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917228/lack-of-isnumeric-function-in-c-sharp) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437882/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-nan-or-isnumeric?lq=1) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137985/c-sharp-code-to-check-whether-a-string-is-numeric-or-not?lq=1) also show the same trend alike. Another way which we could see from those posts are to check by `Visual Basic` `IsNumeric`. Thus, I included that method for the `benchmarking` too.

```
public static bool IsFloatOrDoubleByDot(string str) { //another criterion for float, giving "f" in the last part?
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            return false;
        int dotCounter = 0;
        for (int i = str[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0; i < str.Length; i++) { //Check if it is float
    if (!(char.IsDigit(str, i)) && (str[i] != '.'))
      return false;
    else if (str[i] == '.')
      ++dotCounter; //Increase the dotCounter whenever dot is found
    if (dotCounter > 1) //If there is more than one dot for whatever reason, return error
      return false;
  }
  return dotCounter == 0 || dotCounter == 1 && str.Length > 1;
}

public static bool IsDigitsOnly(string str) {
  foreach (char c in str)
    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
      return false;      
  return str.Length >= 1; //there must be at least one character here to continue
}

public static bool IsInt(string str) { //is not designed to handle null input or empty string
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            return false;           
  return str[0] == '-' && str.Length > 1 ? IsDigitsOnly(str.Substring(1)) : IsDigitsOnly(str);
}
```

---

#### Testing Scenario:

So far, I have tested four different scenarios:

- integer (in the parse-able range by int.TryParse)
- float text containing `dot` (max of 7-digit precision, in the accurate parse-able range by float.TryParse)
- double text containing `dot` (max of 11-digit precision, in the accurate parse-able range by double.TryParse)
- integer text read as float/double text (in the parse-able range by double.TryParse)

And for each scenario, I have four cases to test:

- Valid positive-valued text
- Valid negative-valued text
- Invalid positive-valued text
- Invalid negative-value text

And for each case I tested the time needed to do the checking by:

- Suitable `TryParse`
- Suitable `Extension.Checker.Text`
- `Visual Basic` `IsNumeric`
- Other type-specific tricks like string.All(char.IsDigit) for integer

---

#### Testing Code:

To test the above scenarios, I use the following data:

```
string intpos = "1342517340";
string intneg = "-1342517340";
string intfalsepos = "134251734u";
string intfalseneg = "-134251734u";
string floatpos = "56.34251";
string floatneg = "-56.34251";
string floatfalsepos = "56.3425h";
string floatfalseneg = "-56.3425h";
string doublepos = "56.342515312";
string doubleneg = "-56.342515312";
string doublefalsepos = "56.34251531y";
string doublefalseneg = "-56.34251531y";
List<string> liststr = new List<string>() {
    intpos, intneg, intfalsepos, intfalseneg,
    floatpos, floatneg, floatfalsepos, floatfalseneg,
    doublepos, doubleneg, doublefalsepos, doublefalseneg
};
List<string> liststrcode = new List<string>() {
    "i+", "i-", "if+", "if-",
    "f+", "f-", "ff+", "ff-",
    "d+", "d-", "df+", "df-"
};
bool parsed = false; //to store checking result
int intval; //for int.TryParse result
float fval; //for float.TryParse result
double dval; //for double.TryParse result
```

text code is in the format of . Examples:

- if+ = integer false positive
- f- = float negative

And I use the following testing loop to get the time performance of each method per case:

```
//time snap
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) //for integer case
    parsed = int.TryParse(str, out intval); //built-in TryParse
//time snap
//Print the result
//time snap
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    parsed = Extension.Checker.Text.IsInt(str); //extension Text checker
//time snap
//Print the result
//time snap
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    parsed = Information.IsNumeric(str); //Microsoft.VisualBasic
//time snap
//Print the result
//time snap
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    parsed = str[0] == '-' ? str.Substring(1).All(char.IsDigit) : str.All(char.IsDigit); //misc methods
//time snap
//Print the result
//Print the result difference
```

I tested as many as 10 million iterations per testing case per method using my laptop.

*Note: it is noted that the behavior of my `Extension.Checker.Text` is not completely equivalent with built-in `TryParse` such as checking the range of the numerical value of the string or string with other formats which might be acceptable for `TryParse` case but not in my case. This is because the main purpose of my `Extension.Checker.Text` is not to necessarily convert the given text into certain data type in C# as built-in `TryParse`. And that is the very point of my `Extension.Checker.Text`. The comparisons made here is merely done to compare - in terms of time performance benefits - (1) the [popular way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number) of checking certain text format with (2) the extension method we could possibly made given that we do not need the result of the `TryParse`, but only if a text is of certain format or not. That goes the same for comparison with VB `IsNumeric`*

---

#### Testing Result:

I printed out the `parse/check` result to ensure that my extension has the same result as the built-in `TryParse`, `VB.Net IsNumeric`, and other alternative tricks for the given cases. I also print the original text for easy reading/checking. Then, by the time snap in between the testing, I could get the time performance as well as time difference for each testing case, which I also printed out. The time gain comparison however, is only done with the `TryParse`. Here is the complete result.

```
[2016-01-05 06:04:25.466 UTC] Integer:
[2016-01-05 06:04:26.999 UTC] TryParse i+:  1531 ms Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:27.639 UTC] Extension i+:     639 ms  Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:30.345 UTC] VB.IsNumeric i+:  2705 ms Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:31.468 UTC] All is digit i+:  1124 ms Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:31.469 UTC] Gain on TryParse i+:  892 ms  Percent: -58.26%
[2016-01-05 06:04:31.469 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:04:32.996 UTC] TryParse i-:  1527 ms Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:33.846 UTC] Extension i-:     849 ms  Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:36.413 UTC] VB.IsNumeric i-:  2566 ms Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:37.693 UTC] All is digit i-:  1280 ms Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:04:37.694 UTC] Gain on TryParse i-:  678 ms  Percent: -44.40%
[2016-01-05 06:04:37.694 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:04:39.058 UTC] TryParse if+:     1364 ms Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:39.845 UTC] Extension if+:    786 ms  Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:42.436 UTC] VB.IsNumeric if+:     2590 ms Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:43.540 UTC] All is digit if+:     1103 ms Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:43.540 UTC] Gain on TryParse if+:     578 ms  Percent: -42.38%
[2016-01-05 06:04:43.540 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:04:44.937 UTC] TryParse if-:     1397 ms Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:45.745 UTC] Extension if-:    807 ms  Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:48.275 UTC] VB.IsNumeric if-:     2530 ms Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:49.541 UTC] All is digit if-:     1267 ms Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:04:49.542 UTC] Gain on TryParse if-:     590 ms  Percent: -42.23%
[2016-01-05 06:04:49.542 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:04:49.542 UTC] Float by Dot:
[2016-01-05 06:04:51.136 UTC] TryParse f+:  1594 ms Result: True    Text: 56.34251
[2016-01-05 06:04:51.967 UTC] Extension f+:     830 ms  Result: True    Text: 56.34251
[2016-01-05 06:04:54.328 UTC] VB.IsNumeric f+:  2360 ms Result: True    Text: 56.34251
[2016-01-05 06:04:54.329 UTC] Time Gain f+:     764 ms  Percent: -47.93%
[2016-01-05 06:04:54.329 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:04:55.962 UTC] TryParse f-:  1634 ms Result: True    Text: -56.34251
[2016-01-05 06:04:56.790 UTC] Extension f-:     827 ms  Result: True    Text: -56.34251
[2016-01-05 06:04:59.102 UTC] VB.IsNumeric f-:  2313 ms Result: True    Text: -56.34251
[2016-01-05 06:04:59.103 UTC] Time Gain f-:     807 ms  Percent: -49.39%
[2016-01-05 06:04:59.103 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:00.623 UTC] TryParse ff+:     1519 ms Result: False   Text: 56.3425h
[2016-01-05 06:05:01.429 UTC] Extension ff+:    802 ms  Result: False   Text: 56.3425h
[2016-01-05 06:05:03.730 UTC] VB.IsNumeric ff+:     2301 ms Result: False   Text: 56.3425h
[2016-01-05 06:05:03.730 UTC] Time Gain ff+:    717 ms  Percent: -47.20%
[2016-01-05 06:05:03.731 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:05.312 UTC] TryParse ff-:     1581 ms Result: False   Text: -56.3425h
[2016-01-05 06:05:06.147 UTC] Extension ff-:    835 ms  Result: False   Text: -56.3425h
[2016-01-05 06:05:08.485 UTC] VB.IsNumeric ff-:     2337 ms Result: False   Text: -56.3425h
[2016-01-05 06:05:08.486 UTC] Time Gain ff-:    746 ms  Percent: -47.19%
[2016-01-05 06:05:08.486 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:08.487 UTC] Double by Dot:
[2016-01-05 06:05:10.341 UTC] TryParse d+:  1854 ms Result: True    Text: 56.342515312
[2016-01-05 06:05:11.492 UTC] Extension d+:     1151 ms Result: True    Text: 56.342515312
[2016-01-05 06:05:14.035 UTC] VB.IsNumeric d+:  2541 ms Result: True    Text: 56.342515312
[2016-01-05 06:05:14.035 UTC] Time Gain d+:     703 ms  Percent: -37.92%
[2016-01-05 06:05:14.036 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:15.916 UTC] TryParse d-:  1879 ms Result: True    Text: -56.342515312
[2016-01-05 06:05:17.051 UTC] Extension d-:     1133 ms Result: True    Text: -56.342515312
[2016-01-05 06:05:19.542 UTC] VB.IsNumeric d-:  2492 ms Result: True    Text: -56.342515312
[2016-01-05 06:05:19.543 UTC] Time Gain d-:     746 ms  Percent: -39.70%
[2016-01-05 06:05:19.543 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:21.210 UTC] TryParse df+:     1667 ms Result: False   Text: 56.34251531y
[2016-01-05 06:05:22.315 UTC] Extension df+:    1104 ms Result: False   Text: 56.34251531y
[2016-01-05 06:05:24.797 UTC] VB.IsNumeric df+:     2481 ms Result: False   Text: 56.34251531y
[2016-01-05 06:05:24.798 UTC] Time Gain df+:    563 ms  Percent: -33.77%
[2016-01-05 06:05:24.798 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:26.509 UTC] TryParse df-:     1711 ms Result: False   Text: -56.34251531y
[2016-01-05 06:05:27.596 UTC] Extension df-:    1086 ms Result: False   Text: -56.34251531y
[2016-01-05 06:05:30.039 UTC] VB.IsNumeric df-:     2442 ms Result: False   Text: -56.34251531y
[2016-01-05 06:05:30.040 UTC] Time Gain df-:    625 ms  Percent: -36.53%
[2016-01-05 06:05:30.041 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:30.041 UTC] Integer as Double by Dot:
[2016-01-05 06:05:31.794 UTC] TryParse (doubled) i+:    1752 ms Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:05:32.904 UTC] Extension (doubled) i+:   1109 ms Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:05:35.590 UTC] VB.IsNumeric (doubled) d+:    2684 ms Result: True    Text: 1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:05:35.590 UTC] Time Gain d+:     643 ms  Percent: -36.70%
[2016-01-05 06:05:35.591 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:37.390 UTC] TryParse (doubled) i-:    1799 ms Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:05:38.515 UTC] Extension (doubled) i-:   1125 ms Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:05:41.139 UTC] VB.IsNumeric (doubled) d-:    2623 ms Result: True    Text: -1342517340
[2016-01-05 06:05:41.139 UTC] Time Gain d-:     674 ms  Percent: -37.47%
[2016-01-05 06:05:41.140 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:42.840 UTC] TryParse (doubled) if+:   1700 ms Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:05:43.933 UTC] Extension (doubled) if+:  1092 ms Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:05:46.575 UTC] VB.IsNumeric (doubled) df+:   2642 ms Result: False   Text: 134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:05:46.576 UTC] Time Gain df+:    608 ms  Percent: -35.76%
[2016-01-05 06:05:46.577 UTC] 
[2016-01-05 06:05:48.328 UTC] TryParse (doubled) if-:   1750 ms Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:05:49.434 UTC] Extension (doubled) if-:  1106 ms Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:05:52.042 UTC] VB.IsNumeric (doubled) df-:   2607 ms Result: False   Text: -134251734u
[2016-01-05 06:05:52.042 UTC] Time Gain df-:    644 ms  Percent: -36.80%
[2016-01-05 06:05:52.043 UTC]
```

The conclusions I got from the results so far:

- Best performance gain we can obtain using an extension method such as above is when the text type is **valid positive integer**. The time
  performance gain we could get is as much as 58.26% for the given
  case. Perhaps this owes to the simplicity of the **valid positive integer** text.
- Worst performance gain we can obtain using an extension method such as above is when the text type is **invalid positive double**. The time
  performance gain we could get is only as much as 33.77% for the given
  case.
- For the integer and float/double (with/without dot) text format, to check if a text is of those formats without the need to actually parse it yet, it is possible to speed up the checking process by building our own text extension checker as compared to using built-in `TryParse`. VB `IsNumeric` is rather slower than the rests for all cases (this is also to my surprise, because according to the benchmarking in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number), VB seems to be pretty fast - though not the best).

---

#### Possible uses:

One possible use of this extension checking is in the case where you receive a certain string and you know that it can be of more than one format types (say, integer or double), but you want to check the actual text type first without an actual parsing at the time of checking. For such given case, an extension method may speed up the process.

Another use is in the **computational linguistic** area, where often you want to know the type a text without actually parsing it to be used computationally.

Comment: This is all very nice, However, you might want to take into consideration that most TryParse methods have overloads that takes culture specific information. i.e in some cultures 1,000 is an integer thousand, in others it's a float one with three zeroes after the decimal place. Still got my vote, anyway.

Comment: @ZoharPeled ah, I see... Yes, you are right. My code certainly doesn't take care of that... And that could be part of the reasons for the boost as well. Thanks for the feedback and the vote! :)