# C# Regex to match hexadecimal number between 0 to FE

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regex in c# that validates the hexadecimal number between 0 to FE (i.e. 0 to 254 in decimal)(Case insensitive).

here user can enter the single digit number in two digit. For example number 9  as 09.

any help is appreciated.

Note: We don't need to validate '0x' here,just a range between 0 to FE.

Comment: You want to use... *Regex*??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

Comment: Suggest you attempt to convert to an int (see above link) and check the link.  Use TryParse, in case the string is incorrect.

Comment: I don't want to convert the string,I ant a regex pattern to validate the string.

Comment: @Mahendra But why? Typically, you would use `Parse` or `Convert` or `TryParse` - even just to validate. `Regex` is often "overkill" for most scenarios - it may even perform slower than, let say, `TryParse`. Anyway, if you really need things to check the `string` without actually converting the `string`, I once have such wish too. For some special case, it is indeed beneficial. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392763/tryparse-without-actual-parsing-or-any-other-alternative-for-checking-text-forma perhaps you want to explain your context too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
^(([fF][0-9a-eA-E])|([0-9a-eA-E]?[0-9a-fA-F]))$
```

Some explanations:

This regex contains 2 logical parts. First `([fF][0-9a-eA-E])` matches cases when number starts with "f" or "F", as per original criteria, in that case only 0-9 and A-E is available, to reject "FF".
Second part `([0-9a-eA-E]?[0-9a-fA-F])` handles all other cases, first symbol is 0-9 or A-E (F is covered by first part) or absent (to cover single symbol numbers), and second symbol is any valid for hexdecimal (0-9 A-F).

Comment: Thanks Alex,I was testing it with various numbers and it succeeded.Can you please explain this regex it a bit?

Comment: I've added few explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:[0-9a-eA-E]?[0-9a-fA-F]|[fF][0-9a-eA-E])$
```

It will work with or without leading zero, uppercase or lowercase characters.

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iI9fT3/1)

[Visualization](http://regexper.com/#%5E(%3F%3A%5B0-9a-eA-E%5D%3F%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%7C%5BfF%5D%5B0-9a-eA-E%5D)%24)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
([0-9A-F]{1}[0-9A-E]{1})
```

Comment: This requires the use of two characters.  So this would fail a valid input of `8`.

Comment: It also matches a comma (`,`)

Comment: And without anchors, it matches any string that contains something that could pass as a 2-digit hex number (such as `nnnnnnn0000000000`).

Comment: @ryanyuyu I must've misread the original, i thought it **had** to be 2 digits. And from what it seemed like Mahendra wanted the input would only ever be 2 characters.