# What regex expression would be appropriate?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check if a string last word is either `"...abc" or "...xyz" or "...fgh"`.

How i can achieve the same thing using regex as i am trying to learn it?

> e.g **Sentence 1:** Hi My Name is abc.
>    **Sentence 2:** I live in xyz.

The above sentence is a sample one to demonstrate.

Comment: Do you know how to check if a string is *exactly* either “abc”, “xyz”, or “fgh” with regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any Regex. Just use [`String.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
string a = "asdasd abc";

Console.WriteLine(a.EndsWith("abc.") || a.EndsWith("xyz.") || a.EndsWith("fgh."));
```

Comment: How are you going to check for 3 possibilities using `EndWith()`? You'll need to run it 3 times which is wasteful. What if you need to check for 10 possibilities?

Comment: @RacilHilan no, I  don't need to run 3 times. `||` will work until first `true`.

Comment: @RacilHilan in addition, How do you think your regex will work? It will check for 3 cases as well.

Comment: Yes, it will return the first `true`, but what if it is the last? Then it runs 3 times. And if you need 10 options, then it runs 10 times. And no, regex does not run 3 (or 10 times). Read how regex works. If you benchmark the two solutions, you'll see a big difference. Also repeating the code 3 times (or 10) is really tiring for the eyes :-)

Comment: @RacilHilan as you can see at screenshot it is not exactly that Regex will work better or faster. http://take.ms/Bc58f

Comment: Quick benchmarking :-). But it's not that simple, you need  a much bigger loop and you need to compile the regex. There are people who already benchmarked it on SO, but have a quick look at [this explanation of how regex works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584635). I hope you'll find it useful. Basically, regex is kind of scripted language. For simple cases (e.g. compare only one value) `EndWith` is definitely faster, but for more complex cases (like we're doing here) regex uses smarter methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple regex pattern:

```
(abc|xyz|fgh)$
```

Put your possible options between parenthesis separated by pipes. The `$` means the end of the string.

Comment: Would also consider punctation marks at the end of sentence (not obvious from OP).

Comment: @vasek Yes, that's not clear. If it always ends with period, then add `\.` before `$`.