# c# code to check whether a string is numeric or not

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010.I want to check whether a string is numeric or not.Is there any built in function to check this or do we need to write a custom code?

Comment: The people pointing you towards `TryParse` are correct, but keep in mind that the default is to parse with the current culture active for that request on the server. If you expect a specific culture, you need to pass this in explicitly.

Comment: Why did you accept the *worst* answer?

Answer (score 19):

You could use the [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method. Example:

```
string s = ...
int result;
if (int.TryParse(s, out result))
{
    // The string was a valid integer => use result here
}
else
{
    // invalid integer
}
```

There are also the [float.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx), [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) and [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) methods for other numeric types than integers.

But if this is for validation purposes you might also consider using the [built-in Validation controls in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx). Here's an [example](http://onetidbit.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/14/).

Comment: That will only cover int though, there are lots of other numerics.

Comment: @Jon Egerton, I've updated my answer to take your remark into account.

Answer (score 6):

You can do like...

```
 string s = "sdf34";
    Int32 a;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out a))
    {
        // Value is numberic
    }  
    else
    {
       //Not a valid number
    }
```

Comment: 'numeric' should also include decimal numbers

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Int32.TryParse()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is: `int.TryParse(...)` check the `out bool` param.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question:

[What is the C# equivalent of NaN or IsNumeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437882/c-equivalent-of-nan-or-isnumeric)

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in methods Int.Parse or Double.Parse methods. You can write the following function and call where ever necessary to check it.

```
public static bool IsNumber(String str)
        {
            try
            {
                Double.Parse(str);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since 2005 (.NET 2.0) there are `TryParse` methods - don't use exceptions for normal program flow!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with all the Double/Int32/... `TryParse(...)` methods is that with a long enough numeric string, the method will return false;

For example:

```
var isValidNumber = int.TryParse("9999999999", out result);
```

Here, `isValidNumber` is false and `result` is 0, although the given string is numeric.

If you don't need to use the string as int, I would go with regular expressions validation on this one:

```
var isValidNumber = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$")
```

This will only match integers. "123.45" for example, will fail.

If you need to check for floating point numbers:

```
var isValidNumber = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$")
```

Note: try to create a single `Regex` object and send it to your int testing method for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string Str = textBox1.Text.Trim();
double Num;
bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
if (isNum)
    MessageBox.Show(Num.ToString());
else
    `enter code here`MessageBox.Show("Invalid number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **IsNumeric()** to check whether given string is numeric or not. It always return **True** for numeric value regardless whether it is **Int** or **Double**.

```
string val=...; 
bool b1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    {

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            bool check;
            string testStr = "ABC";
            string testNum = "123";
            check = CheckNumeric(testStr);
            Console.WriteLine(check);
            check = CheckNumeric(testNum);
            Console.WriteLine(check);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static bool CheckNumeric(string input)
        {
            int outPut;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out outPut))
                return true;

            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

This will work for you!!

Answer (score -1):

Try This-->

```
String[] values = { "87878787878", "676767676767", "8786676767", "77878785565", "987867565659899698" };

if (Array.TrueForAll(values, value =>
{
    Int64 s;
    return Int64.TryParse(value, out s);
}
))

Console.WriteLine("All elements are  integer.");
else
Console.WriteLine("Not all elements are integer.");
```

Comment: Why Int64? What about double?